# What can I do with Treasure?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Throughout the entire game, I have sold all the treasure-type items I got. Do they serve any purpose other than profit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Yes.***

Some treasure items are required to upgrade certain weapons you find through the game (denoted by a yellow "+" symbol next to them). Additionally, you may use some treasures as tertiary spell components and significantly boost spell potency, duration, range, or provide a secondary effect that can either help the caster or assail the target with a negative status on top of damage.

Answer (score 1):

Treasure items serve three purposes

#### Item Upgrades

Certain treasure items are used in item upgrades, but this is actually a [pretty short list](http://www.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-15/Upgradable_Weapons), at least relative to the number of treasure items in the game.

- Rusted Bit (Engine Blade 2)
- Glass Gemstone (Engine Blade 3)
- Sturdy Helixhorn (Ultima Blade)
- Metal Scrap (Drain Lance 2)
- Coeurl Whisker (Drain Lance 3)
- Spiked Armor (Absorb Shield 2)
- Barbed Scythe (Plunderers 2)
- Earth Gemstone (Valiant 2)
- Monster Claw (Force Stealer 2)
   - Cactuar Needle (Auto Crossbow Plus)
- Dynamo (Bioblaster Plus)
- Sky Gemstone (Circular Saw Plus)
- Hydraulic Cylinder (Gravity Well Plus)
- Magnetron (Noise Blaster Plus)
- Magitek Core (Drillbreaker Plus)

#### Elemenacy

When creating spells, you can add an item (Medicine, Ingredient, or Treasure) to them. *Any* treasure can be used for Elemancy, with varying effects.

#### Selling

As mentioned in the question, treasures can also be sold for gil. In the postgame content, this may actually make up a non-negligible portion of your income, depending on how you play.